# 18.04: External USB3 HDD fails on the USB3 port with Ubuntu, but works OK in Windows

Tags: 18.04, usb, hard-drive, external-hdd

I have a Silicon Power external hard disk (512GB) which has a USB 3 interface. It works perfectly well with Windows with USB3 mode as well as USB2 mode. 
On my Toshiba (C50-A), I used to run Windows and it has a single USB3 port and it worked fine.

But on Ubuntu, the drive lights up as 3.0 but nothing happens. It works completely fine on the USB2 ports. But on the USB3 port, it outright does nothing. 
- No dmesg outputs.
- Nothing on lsusb
- Nothing on /var/log/syslog

OS is Ubuntu 18.04

```
➜  ~ uname -a
Linux SIGIRIYA 4.15.0-74-generic #84-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 19 08:06:28 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any hints / ideas on why this thing is doing what its doing?

P.S. Requested outputs;

```
journalctl | grep uas
...
entries for today

Jan 15 12:24:32 SIGIRIYA kernel: squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
Jan 15 12:26:12 SIGIRIYA kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
Jan 15 21:46:28 SIGIRIYA kernel: squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
Jan 15 22:36:17 SIGIRIYA kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
Jan 15 22:39:16 SIGIRIYA kernel: squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
Jan 15 22:40:32 SIGIRIYA kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
```

When the disk is on USB2:

```
➜  ~ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 10f1:1a52 Importek 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: sounds like an problem with modul uas. `journalctl | grep uas` please and when plugin to an usb2 port `lsusb`

Comment: Just added them to the question. Just remembered that I can edit the question

Comment: Many motherboards require Asmedia drivers to enable USB3, e.g., Gigabyte, and that firm has no Linux drivers for USB3, only Windows. Would you please be so kind as to provide the make and model of your motherboard, or if a laptop, the model number from the serial number sticker? For laptops, please provide _that_ and  _only_ that model number as model names elsewhere don't provide the detail needed to solve many problems. Once you have it, please click [edit] and add that to the original question; please don't use Add Comment.

Comment: `echo options usb-storage quirks=174c:55aa:u | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist_uas.conf` reboot.

Comment: I will try that when I go home and post the output. As for K7AAY, I have already given the model number which is C50-A Toshiba. I don't know the motherboard model unfortunately.